# Create JMeter JSR223 Sampler programmatically using Java code

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have filecopy code in java. I need to know the process to set the "script" property of jsr223 sampler.
Please look at the following codes and let me know if anything wrong.
**FileCopy Code :-**

copyFileUsingStream Method :-

```
package FileCopyHelper;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

 public class FileCopyGroup {
     public static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) {
          FileInputStream is = null;
          FileOutputStream os = null;
          try {
                 is = new FileInputStream(source);
                 os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                 int length;
             while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
             os.write(buffer, 0, length);
             }
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               System.out.println("Unable to copy file:" + ex.getMessage());
           } finally {
           try {
               is.close();
               os.close();
           } catch (Exception ex) {
          }
        }

        }
     }
```

Main Method:-

```
import java.io.File;


import static FileCopyHelper.FileCopyGroup.copyFileUsingStream;

public class SampleFileCopy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File source = new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Downloads\\Invitation.pdf");
    File dest = new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\cpoied4.pdf"); 
          
    copyFileUsingStream(source,dest);

    }
  }
```

**Created JSR223 Sampler Programmatically:-**

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testbeans.gui.TestBeanGUI;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;



public class JMeterFromScratch {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

        File jmeterHome = new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-5.5\\apache-jmeter-5.5");
        String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");

        if (jmeterHome.exists()) {
            File jmeterProperties = new File(jmeterHome.getPath() + slash + "bin" + slash + "jmeter.properties");
            if (jmeterProperties.exists()) {
                //JMeter Engine
                StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

                //JMeter initialization (properties, log levels, locale, etc)
                JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome.getPath());
                JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterProperties.getPath());
                //JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
                JMeterUtils.initLocale();

                // JMeter Test Plan, basically JOrphan HashTree
                HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

                // JSR223 Sampler

                JSR223Sampler jsr223Sampler = new JSR223Sampler();
                jsr223Sampler.setName("JSR223 Sampler");
                jsr223Sampler.setProperty("cacheKey", "true");
                jsr223Sampler.setProperty("script", "How-Set-the-FileCopy-Script");
                jsr223Sampler.setProperty("scriptLanguage", "java");
                jsr223Sampler.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JSR223Sampler.class.getName());
                jsr223Sampler.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());


                // Loop Controller
                LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
                loopController.setLoops(1);
                loopController.setFirst(true);
                loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
                loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
                loopController.initialize();

                // Thread Group
                ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
                threadGroup.setName("Example Thread Group");
                threadGroup.setNumThreads(1);
                threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
                threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
                threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
                threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

                // Test Plan
                TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Create JMeter Script From Java Code");
                testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
                testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
                testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

                // Construct Test Plan from previously initialized elements
                testPlanTree.add(testPlan);
                HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);
                threadGroupHashTree.add(jsr223Sampler);


                // save generated test plan to JMeter's .jmx file format
                SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + slash + "JSRSample2.jmx"));

                //add Summarizer output to get test progress in stdout like:
                // summary =      2 in   1.3s =    1.5/s Avg:   631 Min:   290 Max:   973 Err:     0 (0.00%)
                Summariser summer = null;
                String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
                if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
                    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
                }


                // Store execution results into a .jtl file
                String logFile = jmeterHome + slash + "JSRSample2.jtl";
                ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
                logger.setFilename(logFile);
                testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

                // Run Test Plan
                jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
                jmeter.run();

                System.out.println("Test completed. See " + jmeterHome + slash + "JSRSample2.jtl file for results");
                System.out.println("JMeter .jmx script is available at " + jmeterHome + slash + "JSRSample2.jmx");
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }

        System.err.println("jmeter.home property is not set or pointing to incorrect location");
        System.exit(1);


    }
}
```

Please suggest solutions for setting the filecopy script in the JSR223 sampler script property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change these lines:

```
jsr223Sampler.setProperty("script", "How-Set-the-FileCopy-Script");
jsr223Sampler.setProperty("scriptLanguage", "java");
```

to these:

```
jsr223Sampler.setProperty("script", "File source = new File(\"C:\\\\Users\\\\hp\\\\Downloads\\\\Invitation.pdf\");\n" +
        "File dest = new File(\"C:\\\\Users\\\\hp\\\\Desktop\\\\cpoied4.pdf\");\n" +
        "\n" +
        "copyFileUsingStream(source, dest);\n" +
        "\n" +
        "static void copyFileUsingStream(File source, File dest) {\n" +
        "    FileInputStream is = null;\n" +
        "    FileOutputStream os = null;\n" +
        "    try {\n" +
        "        is = new FileInputStream(source);\n" +
        "        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);\n" +
        "        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];\n" +
        "        int length;\n" +
        "        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {\n" +
        "            os.write(buffer, 0, length);\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    } catch (Exception ex) {\n" +
        "        System.out.println(\"Unable to copy file:\" + ex.getMessage());\n" +
        "    } finally {\n" +
        "        try {\n" +
        "            is.close();\n" +
        "            os.close();\n" +
        "        } catch (Exception ex) {\n" +
        "        }\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "\n" +
        "}");
jsr223Sampler.setProperty("scriptLanguage", "groovy");
```

As if you want to provide the code via "Script" tab you need to put literally everything there:

[image]

Another option is to compile your `FileCopyGroup` class into a .jar and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), this way you will be able to just [import](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_import.asp) it and call the `copyFileUsingStream` function where required.

Also be informed of the fact that when you choose `java` as the scripting language it's not "real" Java, it's [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) interpreter so I believe [`groovy` would be a way better choice](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).